# Why is my forloop not working?

Tags: java, for-loop, ascii, charat

This is my first question on this site so I'm not sure how to do this, but my question is as follows:
This is just a small piece of a code with multiple methods.
I need to print the ASCII codes of all the characters in a String (input from the user). Now I am trying to use a for-loop which scans the first character prints the ASCII code of it, then scans the next one etc. But at the moment its just printing the first character's ASCII code a few times. Obviously there's something wrong with my for-loop but I've been trying to figure it out and I really can't find it.

```
static String zin(String zin) {
  int length = zin.length();
  char letter = zin.charAt(0);
  int ascii = (int) letter;
    for (int i = 0; i < zin.length(); i++ ) {
    System.out.println((int) ascii);
    }
  return zin;
}
```

Comment: `char letter = zin.charAt(0);` only gets called once, before the loop. You never update `letter` inside of the loop, so you print the same value as many times as the length of the string. Move it inside of the loop to change it for each character.

Comment: The loop won't update `ascii` for you. You need to update it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because you don't re-assign `ascii`. Try this:

```
static String zin(String zin) {
  int i = 0;
  int length = zin.length();

  for ( i = 0; i < zin.length(); i++ ) {
    int ascii = (int)zin.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(ascii);
  }

  return zin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is though you have a for loop you are not iterating through the strung using that for loop. You only get the 1st char of that string. Instead of that use

```
    static String zin(String zin) {
        for (int i = 0; i < zin.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println((int) zin.charAt(i));
        }
        return zin;
    }
```